# delphi cxgrid restrict characters

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

We are working in Delphi 2006 with devexpress.

We have a cxGrid.
We want to restrict the entry of values for a number column, integers between 0 and 999.
If I set the property type to a SpinEdit the initial value is always 0 which is unwanted.

So I left the property value on the column null and set the datatype on the databinding of the column to Smallint.  That works for the most part but an 'e' and '.' and '+' and '-' can still be entered into the column which causes exceptions.

Is some simple way to exclude the 'e' and '.' and '+' and '-' from being entered into the column?

Comment: Great question, Jacques :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial 0 Value can be prevented by setting `UseNullString` to true.

The input of unwanted characters can handled by

```
procedure TForm1.ViewEditKeyPress(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  AEdit: TcxCustomEdit; var Key: Char);
begin
   if AItem = TheColumnWithSpinEdit then
     if (not (Key in ['0'..'9',#8])) then Key := #0;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks bummi.  The UseNullString property doesnt exist on our cxgridDBColumn but I implemented your ViewEditKeyPress code on my view and that works like a charm although AItem = TheColumnWithSpinEdit never validates so I changed it to AItem.Caption = TheColumnWithSpinEdit.Caption.  I also tried casting AItem as TcxGridDBColumn to no avail.  Thanks again.